# HoloLens freezes when the buttons are recognized

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

Since the beginning I have had the problem that the hololens freeze for half a second as soon as the buttons or toggles are recognized. Why is that lag happing, I'm using the buttons given by the mrtk-example-package? It happens only ones, after that everything is fine again.

*Screenshot - Toggles:*
[image]

**--Edit--**

*Screenshot - Inspector view of my vuforia toggle*

```
https://imgur.com/a/EFUxMi1
```

*InteractiveToggle.cs*

```
https://pastebin.com/PkEtGmir
```

Comment: Can you please include a code sample so that we can help you better? Thanks!

Comment: I can paste some code (in 20min), but its nothing that I wrote. I just took the buttons-prefabe that is given by the package and using it the same way. So I did not manipulate anything

Comment: Seems like there are errors slowing you down. Can you give us the console readout?

Comment: @Vakore I edited my post with an screenshot of my inspector view of one toggle and pasted the script.

Comment: @ILiveForVR Yes, Im gonna deploy it on the hololens and watch what the console in VS will show me.

Comment: @ILiveForVR So I guess no error is happening, If I look to the toggles the first time I get no output. But I postet here my whole output: `https://pastebin.com/FYumVrWb`, `XXXXX` is censored stuff

Comment: You could attach the unity profiler, which will tell you what is causing performance issues.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm gonna try that next week. Right now I have to get the major part of my project done and then I will come back to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any text in the Voice Command field by chance, with Requires Gaze checked? If that's the case the Voice Recognizer is initiating.

Comment: For example on the toggles, there is "Keyword Requires Gaze" on (you can see it on the first link in my post and in the second one, the last function), so you can say on and off. I'm gonna turn it off and try it later :)

Comment: The "Keyword Requires Gaze" toggle only matters if there is a string in the Keyword field, otherwise the keyword feature is ignored and we can rule out this as a possible issue. I had to lend out my HoloLens, once I get it back I can run some tests.

Comment: oh man, I tried it when u wrote this, but I didnt change anything. Yesterday I meant to check this freeze again and tried your solution and it worked... thanks!

Comment: In the latest version of MRTK we are using the Speech Commands profile to handle speech recognition so there are not individual voice recognizers running in each interactable anymore. Glad that helped or maybe you pulled a later version of MRTK.